# One parameter subgroups of reductive algebraic groups

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, p-adic-groups

If I have a reductive algebraic group $G$ defined over a non-archimedean local field $F$. We can define a one-parameter subgroup to be a group homomorphism from $G_{m}$ to $G$. I was wondering, if I have a reductive algebraic group $G$ is there a set of steps that one can follow to find the set of one parameter subgroups of $G$.

Or in general, what are good references to read about this?

Comment: Why not $G_a$ as well? The elliptic case doesn't show up as there are no non-trivial morphisms from a projective to an affine scheme. Well, each of the multiplicative ones sits inside a maximal torus. Of theses there are only finitely many conjugacy classes. Next any additive group sits inside a maximal unipotent subgroup and I am not sure, but there might be only one conjugacy class of those.

Comment: These are known as multiplicative cocharacters. Note that they are countably many. (Reductivity of the ambient group plays no role.)